# How to find out which random variable was chosen?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, mathematical-statistics

This question is related to my other question ( [Need help with a model, Whatsapp data analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272101/need-help-with-a-model-whatsapp-data-analysis) ).
Suppose we have random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_m$ bernoulli distributed with probability $p$, $D_1,\cdots,D_m \sim Exp(\lambda_d)$, $P_1,\cdots,P_m \sim Exp(\lambda_P)$ and let $d_i := X_i D_i + (1-X_i)P_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,m$.
Suppose further that $\lambda_d >> \lambda_P$. Then how can we find out by observing only $d_i$ for which $X_i = 1$? In my other question it was suggested to take the mean $\widehat{d}$ of $d_i$ and if $d_i > \widehat{d}$ then to infer that $X_i = 0$. But this procedure is more a heuristic than an actual argument. Does somebody have an idea on how to make this to an argument?

I know of Otsu's method in computer vision to cluster an image into black and white. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) Do you think this method could be applied in this situation?

**Edit:**
By suggestion of  Anthony Quas, I will sort the $d_i$ and then look for a large gap. The gap is found by maximizing the inter-sum of squares as in Otsu's method. Here is the R-code to find the index $I$ at which the cutoff occurs:

```
S <- 0
I <- -1
st <- sort(di)
for(i in seq(2,m-2)){
    A <- st[1:i]
    B <- st[(i+1):m]
    mA <- mean(A)
    mB <- mean(B)
    ssInter <- length(A)*(mA-mean(di))^2+length(B)*(mB-mean(di))^2
   if( ssInter > S){ S <- ssInter; I <- i}
}
```

Comment: Are you assuming that $\lambda_d$ and $\lambda_P$ are known?

Comment: No. They are not known. We only observe the $d_i$ and know that $\lambda_d>>\lambda_P$

Comment: But $p$ is known?

Comment: No unfortunately $p$ is not known also.

Comment: If this is a practical question, do you have an idea for whether $p$ is very close to 0 or 1; or is it reasonable to assume that $p$ is not close to either 0 or 1? Also how large should we think of $m$ as being? (If $m$ is large, you can essentially observe all of $\lambda_d$, $\lambda_P$ and $p$). One last modelling question. You're saying $\lambda_d\gg \lambda_P$. Do you have in mind any kind of estimate for the ratio? (if the ratio is 2, it's very different to 100).

Comment: In the particular case $m = 107$, $\lambda_d = 0.2089175$, $\lambda_P = 0.0001738626$ so here $\lambda_d / \lambda_P = 1201.624$ but I assume for the ratio that it is $>100$. You can think of $m$ as a large number. That is, if the observations are to few $m$ is small, than you can request ( wait in the Whatsapp chat to see some more observations) some more of the $d_i$. Essentially you can assume that $m$ is a large number. $p$ is the probability of chatting. $1-p$ is the probability of pausing. So it should vary with different persons chatting. In this particular case we have $p=0.85$.

Comment: So the cutoff you're using (the sample mean) is way too high. Almost everything (99.99999999%) close to that level is coming from the $P$ distribution; not the $D$ distribution. I'll try and think about a better threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This first paragraph has been corrected**
So assuming everything is known, and that $\lambda_d\gg\lambda_P$, the threshold where you should cut off between assuming $X=1$ and $X=0$ is roughly given by the solution of $pe^{-\lambda_d T}=(1-p)\lambda_P T$.
The left side is the probability that a $d_i$ that is a $D$ value lies above the threshold; and the right side is the probability that a $d_i$ that is a $P$ value lies below the threshold. When I computed the threshold for your parameter values, I got a threshold of 33.

I will assume that $mp$ and $m(1-p)$ are large. Given the very large ratio between $\lambda_P$ and $\lambda_d$, it is quite wasteful to use the mean as the cutoff (it gives too many false $X=1$'s when the $P_i$ happen to be somewhat small relative to $1/\lambda_P$).

Probably quite a good way to locate the cutoff in practice is to sort the $d_i$'s into order and look at the gaps. In the $\lambda_D$ part of the distribution, these should be something like $1/(mp\lambda_d)$, whereas in the $\lambda_P$ part of the distribution, they should be *much* bigger, around $1/(m(1-p)\lambda_P)$. I would try to find a way to guess where the gaps change; and then maybe double the threshold to be safe (you get very few false $D$'s this way and double the number of false $P$'s), but this number is something like 0.1% for your parameter range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However for the values which I gave you I get as the threshold you recommended -57.25386 which is negative and therefore of little practical use. I do not know why it works (what the theoretical reason is) but it seems like letting the mean as a cutoff is ok in practical situations.

Comment: Yes. That seems like a good idea, but still leaves the question open, as how to choose the cutoff automatically. Do you think it is a good idea to try to compute the probability density function of $d_i$ and then to compute what is the probability that $P( P_i > E(d_i) )$ and what is the probability that $P( D_i \le E(d_i))$? If they both are high, then this would explain why the mean as a cutoff is ok

Comment: I have an idea: Choose the cutoff $d$ in such a way that the probability: $P(P_i > d) + P(D_i \le d)$ is maximized. Do you think this can be done mathematically or is it not tractable?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm doing. But of course this is only possible if you know the values of all of the parameters. However: if you do what I'm suggesting, of looking at where the gaps between data points suddenly become large, that should be very close to the best threshold.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Could you please provide the cumulative distribution function? I want to understand what $P(P_i > T) + P(D_i \le T)$ is.

Comment: Sure. I actually did a minimization of $(1-p)\mathbb P(P_i\le T)+p\mathbb P(D_i\ge T)$ (but this is equivalent). The first term is $(1-p)(1-e^{-\lambda_P T})\approx (1-p)\lambda_PT$ (where I'm using the fact that $T\ll 1/\lambda_P)$. The second term is $pe^{-\lambda_dT}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this: the log- likelihood with respect  to the measure in which they are all $\lambda_p$ is $ \sum X_i (log(\frac {\lambda_q}{\lambda_p}) - ({\lambda_p} - {\lambda_q})(Z_i)) + log( {N \choose j} p^j (1-p) ^ {n-j})$, where $Z_i$ is your observation and my X_i are 0 or 1,  however, having chose j I am sure that you maximize the expression by choosing the j largest or j smallest $Z_i$ and then it very likely follows that the estimated $\lambda$s should be  the mean of the largest resp smallest. My claim is that this procedure is reasonable because it is based on maximizing the likelihood.  I would be surprised if this exact problem hasn't been considered, and would search under 'missing data' (the X_i) .  I changed your notation to ps and qs so I could warn you  to watch my p's and q's, the signs may be wrong by the idea  should be correct.

Comment: We do not observe the $\lambda_P$ and $\lambda_d$ only the $d_i$.

Comment: I realize that, why do you think that cause you a problem ?   You could take that expression or a correct version of it and say pick the $\lambda s, X_i, p$ that maximizes, which sounds awkward, but in fact I think that for each value of j ( $= \sum X-I$) you can do  it by inspection or simple calculus and you just need to do one calculation for each j.

Comment: The standard way of finding the MLE (maximum likelihood estimate) parameters with latent variable, such you have here, is the E-M (expectation maximization) algorithm. But, as Michael points out, for your one-dimensional setup here, you get a lot of simplification, and you can almost solve it by hand. Anyway, you might still get a good feel for the problem by reading about E-M: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm